# Fluent NHibernate HasMany where source is BLOB

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a database

```
table ClassA:
  int Id,
  varchar(25) SomeValue 

table ClassB:
  int Id,
  BLOB Items
```

Field ClassB.Items contains int64 array of ids.

My entities:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
   public virtual string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
public class ClassB
{
   public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
   public virtual IList<ClassA> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how can be mapped property ClassB.Items

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746142/fluent-nhibernate-binaryblobtype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ClassB, as byte[] and with type BinaryBlob.

Comment: How to convert BLOB into an array or collection of identifiers I know. but I need a collection of entities.